# consumer group 'fetch_twitter_group' has no active memmbers

Tags: apache-kafka

i use kafka in many scripts but in one of them (the script that connect to twitter api and get messages) after a while in kafka cli monitor it show there is no active member and the offset of consumers is not increase and they stop but the LAG and end-offset is increasing (kafka is work in code and get new messages and go for next but the monitor is not change)

(neither of other script does not get this problem and i restart kafka it look good but after a while it ran into this problem again)

kafka version: 2.7.0
code language: python
platform: ubuntu server 20.04

[image: the picture of kafka cli]

Comment: Hi, could you share the output of your kafka cli as code instead of as image?

Comment: Sounds like your consumer is dying. There's a Kafka connector for Twitter, so do you need python?